# Why does my program not read full files?

Tags: java, io

I have written code in Java to read the content of a file. But it is working for small line of file only not for more than 1000 line of file. Please tell me me what error I have made in the below program.

program:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class aaru
{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException
  {
    File sourceFile = new File("E:\\parser\\parse3.txt");
    File destinationFile = new File("E:\\parser\\new.txt");
    FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);
    DataInputStream dataIn = new DataInputStream(fileIn);
    DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(fileOut);

    String str = "";
    String[] st;
    String sub[] = null;
    String word = "";
    String contents = "";
    String total = "";

    String stri = "";
    try
    {
      while ((contents = dataIn.readLine()) != null)
      {
        total = contents.replaceAll(",", "");
        String str1 = total.replaceAll("--", "");
        String str2 = str1.replaceAll(";", "");
        String str3 = str2.replaceAll("&", "");
        String str4 = str3.replaceAll("^", "");
        String str5 = str4.replaceAll("#", "");
        String str6 = str5.replaceAll("!", "");
        String str7 = str6.replaceAll("/", "");
        String str8 = str7.replaceAll(":", "");
        String str9 = str8.replaceAll("]", "");
        String str10 = str9.replaceAll("\\?", "");
        String str11 = str10.replaceAll("\\*", "");
        String str12 = str11.replaceAll("\\'", "");


        Pattern pattern =
            Pattern.compile("\\s+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str12);
        //boolean check = matcher.find();
        String result = str12;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^www\\.|\\@");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(result);
        stri = m.replaceAll(" ");

        int i;
        int j;

        st = stri.split("\\.");

        for (i = 0; i < st.length; i++)
        {
          st[i] = st[i].trim();
          /*if(st[i].startsWith(" "))
          st[i]=st[i].substring(1,st[i].length);*/
          sub = st[i].split(" ");

          if (sub.length > 1)
          {
            for (j = 0; j < sub.length - 1; j++)
            {
              word = word + sub[j] + "," + sub[j + 1] + "\r\n";

            }
          }
          else
          {
            word = word + st[i] + "\r\n";
          }
        }
      }

      System.out.println(word);
      dataOut.writeBytes(word + "\r\n");

      fileIn.close();
      fileOut.close();
      dataIn.close();
      dataOut.close();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.out.print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Can you add some comments or description to the code to make it a bit easier to follow?  I'm not really able to see what the big picture is here.

Comment: Your formatting and indentation is terrible. It's *very* hard to follow the flow of your program like that. Please remember to always indent code blocks (i.e. "stuff within { }").

Comment: Also: describing the actual problem (i.e. which output you see versus which output you expect) helps *a lot*.

Comment: Why do you think it's not reading the whole file? Did you check it with the debugger or did you try inserting debugging output? If you judge by the results only, it could very well be that it does read the whole file, but there is a bug in your processing.

Comment: Suggested edit collision, sorry...

Answer (score 3):

It's not immediately obvious why your code doesn't read full files, but here are two hints:

First: Don't use a `DataInputStream` for reading full lines. Instead wrap your `FileInputStream` in a [`InputStreamReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) (ideally providing an encoding) and a [`BufferedReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) (as documented by the JavaDoc of [`DataInputStream.readLine()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine%28%29)):

Like this:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileIn, "UTF-8"));
```

Second: when you don't know how to handle an exception *at least* print its stack trace like this:

```
catch(Exception e)
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```